# Copy the reply button to each comment thread in WordPress. Converted from jQuery to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I converted an old Wordpress Plugin of mine from jQuery to plain JavaScript using a cheat sheet. I was very surprised that it seems to work right out of the box on my first try.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {

        $('.comment-list > li .comment-reply').each(function () {

            var reply = this;

            /* collect every comment which needs a reply link */
            var allchildren = $(reply).parent().children('.children').children().find(".comment-content");

            $.each(allchildren, function (index, value) {
                $(reply).clone().appendTo(value);
            });

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Became this:

```
const replybtns = document.querySelectorAll(".comment-list > li .comment-reply");

for (let i = 0; i < replybtns.length; i++) {
    let replybtn = replybtns[i];
    let replybtncp = replybtn.cloneNode(true);
    let cc = replybtn.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.children div.comment-content');
    let lastcc = cc[Object.keys(cc)[Object.keys(cc).length - 1]];
    lastcc.appendChild(replybtncp);
}
```

This copies all reply links of all level 1 nested comments and appends them to the last comment.

Is this code okay? Is it really that simple? I tested it with Firefox and Chrome, and it seems to work. I know that it appends the reply link only to the last element. I did that on purpose to make it simpler.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your post looks good, hope you get some good answers!